# How to see the my own deleted questions?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

I raised a question in WordPress Stack Exchange few months before. Now I found a answer for that question, So I was searching my question in my profile. But I don't see any where in my question section. I also checked the delete questions by clicking link bottom of the questions in my profile, but there is empty.

It's simply vanished. I doubt the question maybe closed by community. How do I know the question closed or anyway to see the question back. I had some useful information there!

Comment: If I were to look for your question how would I identify it?

Comment: my questions about settings Api (may be tagged). My question was about how to change the settings default error message "Settings saved.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just undeleted it. It got a downvote attached, low views count and no activity since 11 months. Therefore the community user/bot seem have decided to delete it.

Comment: I feel really annoying, It was not even notified! It's like suddenly vanished!!!

Comment: @gowri That's how the system works: It cleans itself up. I mean... 11 month no activity :)

Comment: Doing thing 11 Months inactive question are invalid. It hurts, smiles are not enough! Shall take your apologies. I feel system works in wrong manner. Every person willing to know what happens to their own effort in feature. You have the keys, So I think you can unlock or suggest the idea (annoying)!!!

Comment: Inactivity ==(=) Invalid ?

Comment: I ain't got the keys to the StackExchange network. The only keys I got are the ones to my apartment.

Comment: @gowri A question without _any_ activity (comments, answers, updates by the asker) for eleven months is clearly not useful or interesting. If we would leave such questions open, our answer rate would go down to a point where new members would think, most of the questions don’t get answers. Next time you get no answers, update the question with your ongoing research efforts.

Comment: @kaiser: :) ... I thought you are one of the [moderator](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3792/4022).

Comment: @toscho: I understand what you mean and I accept it. But my point was user should get notified, suddenly vanishing something from someone is appreciated.

Comment: @gowri I agree. But that’s not in our hands. We don’t see it when the bot is cleaning up.